# Dual monitors: gnome-session over ssh with x11 forwarding - set resolution to fit on just one monitor

Tags: ssh, resolution, multiple-monitors, x11-forwarding

I have two monitors with different resolutions (1440x900 and 1600x1200) on Windows 7. I am connecting to a Red Hat machine via ssh through cygwin/x with x11 forwarding.

When I start a gnome-session to get the desktop environment, it opens over both monitors with a window size of 3040x1200. Part of it is not displayed on my smaller monitor.

```
$ startxwin &
$ ssh -Y redhat
[user@redhat ~]$ gnome-session
```

I am unable to change the size of the window by dragging the corners. Is there a way to force the resolution to make the window fit on just one of the monitors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using `startx` instead, which starts a single-window x session. This is much better for launching gnome-session and confines it to a single monitor.

```
$ nohup startx &
$ ssh -Y redhat
[user@redhat ~]$ gnome-session
```